# Google colab doesn't display errors, graphs, any image results while working with python and tensorflow for Image classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using notebooks(Jupyter and google colab) but whenever there is an error, or image to be displayed as a result, or graph. When I run the code there is only empty space displayed for those image results or error, but there is no actual results displayed.

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Hi Immanuel, could you resolve this issue?

Comment: No @user3279414, I don't understand why it happens sometimes and works fine other times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image('yourimage.png')
```